# Are my funds now lost for ever?

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I wanted to as much my funds in BITCOINS to be exchangeed and transfared to my SKRILL ACCOUNT in €.
So in the ATOMIC cryptowallet I choose the lowest fee for this transaction. I sent BTC to the exchanger on 31st of January 2024 around 11 o'cock in the afternoon and today is 4th of February 2024 and my transaction has still STATUS **PENDING**.
ARE MY FUNDS LOST FORBEVER? BUT WHY THEN ATOMIC WALLET OFFERS SO LOW FEES?
OR IF MY FUNDS ARW NOT LOST, HOW LONG I WILL HAVE TO WAIT UNTIL MY FUNDS WILL BE IN MY SKRILL ACCOUNT OT BACK TO MY ATOMIC CRYPTOWALLET?

MY HASH: b6a37f8459f0e76f8fb5fb7f63c51048dae65b7b847f3c7ce63dcb27746d94f4

Answer (score 0):

> **Are my funds now lost for ever?**

No, funds sent in transactions that are not yet confirmed are still under the control of the sender. No one else has control over them.

See [information about your transaction at a blockchain explorer](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/b6a37f8459f0e76f8fb5fb7f63c51048dae65b7b847f3c7ce63dcb27746d94f4)

> ```
> Your transaction fee:  1 satoshi per byte
> Recommended fee:      52 satoshi per byte
>
> Transaction status:           Waiting for confirmations 0 of 6
> Est. time to 1 confirmation:  in 1 day
> ```

That particular explorer's estimate seems optimistic.

See https://bitcoinfees.net/

[image: chart showing expected confirmation time for various fee rates]

Remember, the transaction-fee you offer is effectively your bid in an auction of space in the next block of the blockchain. Your low-bid transaction will wait until miners run out of transactions with higher bids. That might take months with a very very low bid

The appropriate actions available are described in [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)